# Can't create object from array in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a new model object:

```
$ts = Carbon::create(2020, 04, 16, 13, 00, 0, null);
$m1 = new Measure(['time' => $ts]);
dd($m1);
```

but when I check the result of `$m1->time` is null

Here is my model configuration:

```
class Measure extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'measures';
    protected $casts = [
        'time' => 'datetime'
    ];
    public $timestamps = [
        "time"
    ];

    public $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];
}
```

If I do:

```
$m1 = new Measure();
$m1->time = $ts;
```

I will be able to see `$m1->time` value

Why is it happening ?

Comment: see if adding time in the fillable array works

Comment: yes, it worked ! But isn't it supposed to also work with $guarded ?

Comment: $guarded prevents pass assignment while $fillable allows it.

Comment: You can put it as answer ! Thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` fields needs to be specified in the `$fillables` array for it to be mass assignable (from an array while creating new model).

So in the model, the fillable array needs to be defined like so:

```
class Measure extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'measures';
    protected $casts = [
        'time' => 'datetime'
    ];
    public $timestamps = [
        "time"
    ];

    public $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];
    
    //**** fillables array *****//
    protected $fillable = ['time'];
}
```